# Kafka Streams number of threads, on repartition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams application, reading from one Kafka topic with 5 partitions.

The data is then aggregated/repartitioned several times.

I tried to find the recommendation for the number of threads in this scenario, but find it difficult to understand. The [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/architecture) writes as follows:

> You can start as many threads of the application as there are input
>   Kafka topic partitions

Which means in my case 5 threads are the maximum number of effective threads.

But, [this blog](http://aseigneurin.github.io/2017/08/04/why-kafka-streams-didnt-work-for-us-part-2.html), claims that a repartition doubles the number maximum effective threads:

> ... This topic is automatically created with the same
>   number of partitions as the source topic, meaning our application was
>   now reading from 16 partitions with 8 threads, thus creating some kind
>   of contention.

Which is also reasonable to me, because Kafka Streams will have to read from the internal topics it creates too.

So, is the maximal number of effective thread 5 partitions, or 5*(repartitions)?

Answer (score 2):

You can start as many threads as you like. However, only a certain amount of threads will be utilized, while all others would be idle.

> The maximum number of utilized threads is the number of tasks that are created.

A topology is split into sub-topologies and the number of input topic partitions of each sub-topology determines the number of created tasks per sub-topology. If you configures standby tasks, you get additional tasks that can utilize threads, too.

In general, it's hard to tell up-front how many task Kafka Streams created. You can get the sub-topologies via `Topology#describe()`. If all topics have the same number of partitions, the number of task would be `#numPartition * #numSubTopoogies`.

The docs are simplified on purpose, because the exact number of tasks is hard to determine in advance because there are many dependencies. Also, usually one does not need a thread per task and a rule of thumb is good enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
In the file system I have in /tmp/kafka-streams/MY_APP/  a lot of dirs like 0_0 .. 9_4.
Is the count of those directories the number of tasks (and hence the maximum number of utilized threads)?

Comment: Yes. Those are task directories.